# Unable to change checkbox in react hooks

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks

I started learning React hooks, but I am stuck with a basic behavior of `checkbox`. I simply want to toggle my checkbox on click / change. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

**Code -**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(true);

  const handleChange = e => {
    e.persist();
    console.log(e.target.checked);
    setChecked({ checked: !e.target.checked });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="list">
          <div className="search">Search</div>
          <div className="list">
            <ul>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={checked}
                onChange={handleChange}
                onClick={handleChange}
              />
            </ul>
            {JSON.stringify(checked)}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit priceless-herschel-wqxzk]

Comment: You have extra "!". `setChecked({ checked: e.target.checked });` should solve the problem

Comment: Just so you know you were setting state as an object property { checked } which overrode your boolean state. if you ever have to do this in the future, and set the state object properly, make sure you call it by the object property on your input which is checked.checked in this case. I would advise you to make it as simple as possible though so you don't have to ever access an object property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is you are firing the `handleChange` function two times.

Using the previous state of your `checked` state as:

```
const handleChange = e => {
   e.persist();
   setChecked(prevState => !prevState);
};
```

And also removing `onChange` from your `input` element as:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={checked} onClick={handleChange} />
```

Just tested this solution and seemed to be working fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the actual root cause

Comment: You should leave this as onChange. There are other ways other than clicking to change a checkbox which will make this not fire. If Nesh doesn't check for the value of the checkbox and just does a !state it can save the wrong state of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const handleChange = e => {
    e.persist();
    console.log(e.target.checked);
    setChecked({ checked: !e.target.checked });
  };
```

This is failing because you are setting `checked` to an Object but you initialise the state with a boolean

```
   const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(true);
```

---

Changing it to this, should work

```
  const handleChange = e => {
    setChecked(prevValue => !prevValue);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if your trying to just toggle checked or not checked, checkbox default is set you just have to return the checkbox as below, from what i can see your setting checked={checked}

     <div className="App">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="list">
              <div className="search">Search</div>
              <div className="list">
                <ul>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                  />
                </ul>
                {JSON.stringify(checked)}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>




or you could also do the following what i do sometimes, if im doing anything wrong i would love to be corrected.

 const handleChange = e => {
    setChecked(!checked);
  };

<input
                type="checkbox"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

another thing you could do is add the following to the handle check

```
if(checked === true) {
  setChecked(false)
}else {
  setChecked(true)
}
```